# Openproject installing to PostGre instead of MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ubuntu, openproject

Installing Openproject to a rented Ubuntu 18.04 server.

After following installation procedure as described at https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/#installation, I'm at the initial configuration stage.

```
openproject configure
```

Output begins:

```
Launching installer for openproject...
Selected addons: legacy-installer postgres apache2 repositories smtp memcached openproject
```

It should read:

```
Selected addons: legacy-installer mysql apache2 repositories smtp memcached openproject
```

Takes me to the page `postgres/autoinstall`. Should be `mysql/autoinstall`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OpenProject 8.3.0, the packaged installation only provides automatic installers for PostgreSQL for several reasons, among others:

- MySQL was / is not supported on all distributions we support, so we had to rely on MariaDB on some flavors that resulted in problems when trying to detect whether a DBMS was already present. This has caused troubles for users with existing custom MySQL packages on these distributions, since the autoinstall wizard will remove that package on-the-fly
- Some features of OpenProject are not supported, or less performant on stable MySQL versions (which is often still 5.6. on distributions we support). One example is the full text search, which comes with MySQL 8.0 but is highly different from PostgreSQL. OpenProject is slowly going to shift to PostgreSQL.

For more information, here's the release blog with a section regarding this change: https://www.openproject.org/openproject-8-3-0-released/

Comment: On a local install of Ubuntu (16.04, VirtualBox), OpenProject 8.3.0 installed to MySQL, though the install has since crashed and I can not get it back up and running. Would it be possible to convert the database contents?

Comment: Sorry to heae you're installation crashed. The 8.3.0 package has no ties to MySQL anymore so I assume you had an older package installed at some point in time? Please drop me a mail at mail@(my username).de with your current configuration, that would help me identify the issue. You can migrate to PostgreSQL with this guide: https://www.openproject.org/operations/upgrading/migrating-packaged-openproject-database-postgresql/